# Oracle : ora-01850 when comparing a date to sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

I get the following error when comparing a date to sysdate  : ORA-01850 : Hours must be between 0 and 23.

Here is my query :

```
with cr as
 (select '1-2' heures from dual)
select mydate, to_date(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')
  from (select to_char(extract(year from sysdate), 'fm0009') ||
               to_char(extract(month from sysdate), 'fm09') ||
               to_char(extract(day from sysdate), 'fm09') ||
               to_char(h2.heure, 'fm09') || '45' mydate
          from (select to_number(h.intervalle_debut + i.l) heure
                  from (select to_number(regexp_substr(cr.heures,
                                                       '[^-]+',
                                                       1,
                                                       1))         intervalle_debut,
                               to_number(regexp_substr(cr.heures,
                                                       '[^-]+',
                                                       1,
                                                       2)) intervalle_fin
                          from cr) h,
                       (select level - 1 l from dual connect by level <=     24) i
                 where h.intervalle_fin - h.intervalle_debut >= i.l) h2)
where to_date(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') > sysdate;
```

Little explaination :

The subquery "h2" returns these two lines :

```
heure
------
1
2
```

It corresponds to the range 1-2 given in the "cr" subquery.
h2 creates a date corresponding to today using the returned hours. It also returns these two lines :

```
mydate
-------
201708030145
201708030245
```

The dates look fine. Hours are 1 and 2 (this is correct !).

Executing the full query without the where clause returns these two dates :

```
TO_DATE(MYDATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MI
------------------------------
03/08/2017 01:45:00
03/08/2017 02:45:00
```

This is still correct.
BUT, when adding the where clause "to_date(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') > sysdate", I get ORA-01850.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Why are you storing a date in a `varchar` column?

Comment: The complicated way to convert `sysdate` to a character value can be simplified to `to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmddhh42')||'45'`

Comment: Instead of `to_char(extract(year from sysdate), 'fm0009') || to_char(extract(month from sysdate), 'fm09') || to_char(extract(day from sysdate), 'fm09') || to_char(h2.heure, 'fm09') || '45' mydate` you can make simpler `TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate) + h2.heure/24 + 45/24/60, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')`

Comment: The query is not the real one. I wrote one which reproduces the problem without having to create any table. Sure it can be simplified but it's not my question. The problem is : "Why Oracle throws an error while comparing two dates ?".

Answer (score 0):

Yes really strange. This one is working:

```
SELECT mydate, TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')
FROM ...;
```

but this one not:

```
SELECT mydate, TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')
FROM ...
WHERE TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') > SYSDATE;

ORA-01850: hour must be between 0 and 23
```

I made some reformatting and simplified it. This one is working (but I don't know why, i.e. I don't know why your query does not work)

```
WITH cr AS
    (SELECT '1-2' heures FROM dual),
i AS 
    (SELECT LEVEL - 1 l FROM dual connect BY LEVEL <= 24),
h AS
    (SELECT 
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(cr.heures, '[^-]+', 1, 1)) intervalle_debut,
        TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(cr.heures, '[^-]+', 1, 2)) intervalle_fin
    FROM cr),
h2 AS 
    (SELECT 
        TO_NUMBER(h.intervalle_debut + i.l) heure
    FROM h JOIN i ON h.intervalle_fin - h.intervalle_debut >= i.l),
t AS 
    (SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE) + h2.heure/24 + 45/24/60, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') mydate
    FROM h2)
SELECT mydate, TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')
FROM t
WHERE TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi') > SYSDATE;
```

What is the actual intention of your query? Ìt looks a bit over-killing to me. This one does the same:

```
WITH cr AS
    (SELECT '1-2' heures FROM dual),
h AS 
    (SELECT 
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(cr.heures, '[^-]+', 1, 1) intervalle_debut,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(cr.heures, '[^-]+', 1, 2) intervalle_fin
    FROM cr),
t as    
    (SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + (LEVEL-1+intervalle_debut)/24 + 45/24/60 AS mydate
    FROM h
    CONNECT BY LEVEL-1+intervalle_debut BETWEEN intervalle_debut AND intervalle_fin)
SELECT mydate
FROM t
WHERE mydate > SYSDATE;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I managed to rewrite the query to avoid the error which is really strange for me. Could it be related to a bug ?

Comment: Perhaps it is related to [EXTRACT](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm#SQLRF00639) function: _EXTRACT interprets expr as an ANSI datetime data type. For example, EXTRACT treats DATE not as legacy Oracle DATE but as ANSI DATE, without time elements. Therefore, you can extract only YEAR, MONTH, and DAY from a DATE value._ - just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

`TO_DATE(mydate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')>TO_DATE(sysdate, 'yyyymmddhh24mi')`

Comment: While this code snippet may be a solution, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.